# How to plan job in php script via exec and 'at'

Tags: php, exec, at-job

I try to plan one-time job with 'at' command. There is next code in script:

```
$cmd = 'echo "/usr/bin/php '.$script_dir.$script_name.' '.$args.'"|/usr/bin/at "'.$time.'" 2>&1';
exec($cmd, $output , $exit_code);
```

When I run this command from script it adds the job to the schelude. This I see by the line in logs `job 103 at Thu Sep  3 15:08:00 2015` (same text contains `$output`). But then nothing happens in specified time like `at` ignores the job. And there are no error messages in logs.

When I run same command with same args from command line on server it scheludes the job and than runs it at specified time.

I found out that when I try to plan a job via php script it runs under `apache` user. I tried to run next in command line on server:

```
sudo -u apache echo "/usr/bin/php /var/www/pant/data/www/pant.com/scripts/Run.php firstarg secondarg "|/usr/bin/at "16:00 03.09.2015"
```

It works correct too. I checked sudoers and have added apache user with NOPASSWD privileges. Script Run.php has execute rights.

`at.deny` is empty. `at.allow` does not exist.

So question is: why 'at' does not run command given via php script (exec) but runs same command in command line? How to run it? 
Thanks to all.

Comment: What contains `$output` and `$exit_code` from `exec` call? It can answer your question, so why not look at it?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy it contains `Array\n(\n    [0] => job 125 at Thu Sep  3 17:25:00 2015\n)\n 0`

Comment: So it looks that it's working actually, because this is how at's successful output looks exactly, isn't it?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy it looks like it adds task to schelude but than nothing happens. Php script is not run.

Comment: If you execute the same command manually from shell, is it executed by `at` than? You can also print or log what you're sending to `exec` in `$cmd`, so you can check if it's composed right.

Comment: when I do `$cmd = '/usr/bin/php '.$script_dir.$script_name.' '.$args;
exec($cmd, $output , $exit_code);` it works perfectly. but as soon as I try to use `at` nothing happens.

Comment: No, I meant print content of `$cmd` you're passing to `exec`, copy that to shell and execute. Is your command executed by `at` than?

Comment: yes, it executes with `at` from shell without any problem. I run in the shell same command that I pass to exec().

Answer (score 0):

I found by chance answer at [stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101130/create-a-cronjob-to-run-php-script):

> The "problem" is typically PHP is intended to run as module in a webserver. You may need to install the commandline version of php before you can run php scripts from the commandline